# Proper probability distribution formatting for DistributionFitTest

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to use an exponentially modified gaussian to fit a distribution, but I think I may be misunderstanding something about how probability distributions work in Mathematica.
Running

```
DistributionFitTest[data, NormalDistribution[mu, sigma], "FittedDistribution"]
```

works for a gaussian but

```
DistributionFitTest[data,
  ProbabilityDistribution[E^((x - \[Mu])^2 / \[Sigma]^2) /
    (\[Sigma] (2*Pi)^(1/2)),
  {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], "FittedDistribution"]
```

does not. Does anybody know why this is happening? Once I clear this up I should be able to use other PDFs like the exponentially modified gaussian properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

An exponentially modified Gaussian distribution (EMG) describes the sum of independent normal and exponential random variables. [`wiki`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution)

```
SeedRandom[1234];

n = 200;

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 1], n] + 
   RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], n];

{min, max} = MinMax[data];
m = Mean[data];
s = StandardDeviation[data];
```

From the definition of an EMG and using [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html)

```
distEMG1 = TransformedDistribution[x + y,
   {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[μ, σ],
    y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[λ]}];
```

The [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html) is

```
PDF[distEMG1, x]

(* 1/2 E^(1/2 λ (-2 x + 2 μ + λ σ^2)) λ * 
    Erfc[(-x + μ + λ σ^2)/(Sqrt[2] σ)] *)
```

Estimating the distribution from the data using [`EstimatedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EstimatedDistribution.html)

```
estDist1 = 
 EstimatedDistribution[data, 
  distEMG1, {{μ, m}, {σ, s}, {λ, 1}}]

(* TransformedDistribution[\[FormalX]1 + \[FormalX]2, {\[FormalX]1 \
\[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[2.9841, 0.849997], \[FormalX]2 \[Distributed] 
   ExponentialDistribution[1.99775]}] *)

DistributionFitTest[data, estDist1, "PValueTable"]
```

[image]

Using `TransformedDistribution` the constrains on the parameters are automatically taken from the underlying distributions. However, if the distribution is defined with [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html), you must specify the constraints on the parameters as [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
dpa = DistributionParameterAssumptions[distEMG1]

(* μ ∈ Reals && σ > 0 && λ > 0 *)

distEMG2 = 
  ProbabilityDistribution[PDF[distEMG1, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> dpa];
```

Estimating the distribution from the data

```
estDist2 = 
 EstimatedDistribution[data, 
  distEMG2, {{μ, m}, {σ, s}, {λ, 1}}]

(* ProbabilityDistribution[
 0.998876 E^(0.998876 (7.41156 - 2 \[FormalX]))
   Erfc[0.831893 (4.42746 - \[FormalX])], {\[FormalX], -∞, ∞}] *)
```

However, this form of the distribution does not play well with [`DistributionFitTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionFitTest.html) and the following is **very** slow to evaluate.

```
DistributionFitTest[data, estDist2, "PValueTable"]
```

[image]

Comparing the [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html) of the data with the `PDF` of the `EstimatedDistribution`s

```
Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[{PDF[estDist1, x], PDF[estDist2, x]}, {x, min, max},
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Blue, Dashed}},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

[image]